# Chrome runtime.Port onDisconnect firing multiple times

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a web extension where the content script is communicating with the service worker via `browser.runtime.connect({name: 'processor'})` and stores the port as a class field. The service worker listens for new ports and keeps a dictionary to keep track of them and removes them from the list when a disconnect occurs. Both scripts listen for `onDisconect` and `onMessage` and both use `port.postMessage()` to send messages. Neither ever explicitly calls `disconnect()`.

Recently I discovered that the service worker logs have a higher number of log messages for port disconnects than new connections. What I'm seeing is after a new port is registered an `onDisconnect` for that same port follows almost immediately. However sometimes the port seems to persist and I'll continue to receive messages relating to the corresponding tab. I'll also end up seeing a second call to `onDisconnect` when I close the tab, but only in situations where other messages keep flowing too. When I handle a disconnect I am removing the port from the dictionary but not unsubscribing from the events, so apparently the object is not getting disposed and is still in use despite the `onDisconnect` firing?

Additionally, for my current tests, when I open a new tab and navigate to a webpage the issue (sometimes) manifests itself. However if I press F5 to refresh the page then the port doesn't immediately disconnect. Navigating to different webpages first doesn't seem to make a difference, only an explicit refresh seems to change things. Though honestly I'm still fighting to isolate the cause of the behaviors and tests aren't yielding 100% consistent results.

This issue is present in old code that we considered to be working fine, so we're not sure if we somehow missed something or if a change in Chrome may be causing issues?

Comment: The service worker is not persistent unlike the MV2 background script, [more info](/a/66618269).

Comment: If it was the service worker shutting down the the service worker wouldn't be maintaining a log during the time when it was shutdown. I also don't think it would be receiving the event if it was the one shutting down the port. Nor do I think the service worker will go inactive after less than a second of inactivity. @wOxxOm

Comment: It may be a bug. There are lots of bugs in ManifestV3 implementation of SW so the workarounds we have to use aren't exactly based on logic.